# What's a good PHP alternative to Timthumb for creating thumbnails?

Tags: php, caching, thumbnails, timthumb

As Timthumb is now unsupported is there anything which can replace it? I need to create smaller copies of large photos automatically (800*600) and the only suggestions I see when searching on Google is for Wordpress functions to replace Timthumb functionality but I'm not using a CMS package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://github.com/avalanche123/Imagine

Best image processing lib for a few years now. OOP, unit tested, easy to use and MIT licensed. If someone knows another one of the same quality I would be surprised and like to know about it as well. :)

Comment: Wow that looks powerful, thank you very much!

Comment: There is also a helpful library to convert and resize images on the flow like TimTumb did: https://packagist.org/packages/jukuan/img-to-web

Answer (score 0):

Use this one..

This is the simplest resizer
http://www.mywebmymail.com/?q=content/easyphpthumbnail-class

Comment: Could you please show how to implement it directly in the image source link <img src=""> Like TimThumb? `src="timthumb.php?src=image.jpg&w=200&h=100"`